# Spring AOP does not work with a small functions

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a typical task to check proceed time of many functions. I made an annotation

```
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface ProceedTimeLogger {}
```

and an aspect for this annotation

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ProceedTimeLoggerAspect {
public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProceedTimeLoggerAspect.class);

@Around(value = "(@within(com.security.annotation.ProceedTimeLogger) " +
                "|| @annotation(com.security.annotation.ProceedTimeLogger))" +
        "|| execution(* com.security.permissions.permissions.*+.*(..))")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
    String methodId = getMethodId();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info("method '{}' id={} started", methodName, methodId);

    Object proceed = pjp.proceed();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    LOGGER.info("method '{}' id={} proceed time = {} ms", methodName, methodId, end);

    return proceed;
}

public String getMethodId() {
    String randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return randomUUID.substring(randomUUID.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, randomUUID.length());
}
}
```

Now my annotation covers som about 40 classes, but from all of this classes it works only in one method:

```
@Component
@ProceedTimeLogger
public class Permission {
...some methods...
//this function covers!!
public PermissionDTO getDTO(String permissionVal, String productDictId) {
        PermissionDTO result = new PermissionDTO();
        result.setMenuView(isMenuView(productDictId));
        result.setDataView(isDataView(productDictId));
        result = initOptionalDtoFields(result, productDictId);
        return result;
}
...another non-covered methods...
public String getProductType(String productDictId) {
    if (productDictId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Product product = dataDispatcher.getDictionaryById(Product.class, Long.valueOf(productDictId));
    return Optional.ofNullable(product.getType())
            .map(BaseDict::getIdMDMP)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .orElse(null);
}

@ProceedTimeLogger
public String getProductCategory(String productDictId) {
    if (productDictId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Product product = dataDispatcher.getDictionaryById(Product.class, Long.valueOf(productDictId));
    return Optional.ofNullable(product.getProductCategory())
            .map(BaseDict::getIdMDMP)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .orElse(null);

}
}
```

Wtat's different? Why does these methods are not being covered?

Comment: It would be great if you could show us code which does not work, instead the one which actually works :)

Comment: @HerrDerb I can't, the only works function is 'getDTO', and I would like you to find difference benween this and the other two functions, except one of those marked by '@ProceedTimeLogger' (((